# Memory leak in app extension with UIAlertAction attached to UiViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am developing an app extension that takes an url and upload it to a web service.

If there are errors in the upload request, an Alert should pop up and when the user dismisses it, the extension should complete.

Profiling this code with instruments show a memory leak with two NSISLinearexpression objects.

I found that the incriminating code is found in the UIAlertAction that dismisses the alert: without an action attached to the alert the leak disappear.

I'm supposing for some reason calling:

```
self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: nil, completionHandler: nil)
```

causes troubles with the dismiss of the UIAlertController.

Why is that happening?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Social

class ShareViewController: UIViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchStuff()
}

private func sendAlert(alertMessage:String) {

    print("alerting")

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Send video to Kodi", message: alertMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
        UIAlertAction in
        print("Cancel Pressed")
        self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: nil, completionHandler: nil)
        }
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

private func fetchStuff() -> Void {
    print("fetching")
    guard let extensionItem = extensionContext?.inputItems[0] as? NSExtensionItem else {
        print("Unable to get extensionItem")
        return
    } // check for only 1 attachment
    let itemProvider = extensionItem.attachments as! [NSItemProvider]
    let item = itemProvider.first
        if (item?.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.url"))! {
            item?.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: "public.url", options: nil, completionHandler:
                { [weak self] (item: NSSecureCoding?, error: Error?) -> Void in
                    if let url = item as? NSURL {
                        print(url.absoluteString!)
                        self?.sendAlert(alertMessage: "test")
                    }
            })
        }
        else {
            return
        }
    return
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring [unowned self] to the cancelAction closure?

Comment: Yes, still leaking.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar issue.

The cause of the issue for me was that the CoreData manager we built worked off the main dispatch queue. So when the core data manager called our completion block it was actually on a different queue. I added:

DispatchQueue.main.async { }

Around my dialog creation and present calls and the leak disappeared. Hope it helps :)